# Make Author's Last name uppercase, leave first name intact and more

Tags: apa-style, capitalization, custom-bib

I need help adjusting my reference list (not the in-text citation).

[image: current and desired reference entry]

I adjusted the existing apalike.bst for capitalization of the author name  by inserting the below functions and renaming the file [apalike2.bst](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4004629/apalike2.bst).

```
`FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
{ "" }
{ author format.names scapify }
if$
}`

`FUNCTION {smallcaps}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "" }
{ "{\sc " swap$ * "}" * }
if$
}`
```

My formatting tasks:

1. Do not capitalize the first name of the author, only the last name.
2. The 'and' between the author names should be lowercase.
3. Insert a dot before the (year) brackets and remove dot after the (year).
4. Replace colon before the page numbers by a comma.

I don't want to create a new .bst file with makebst from scratch (I tried and failed to get everything right), but I'd like to adjust my existing apalike2.bst file or add commands to the latex file for my purposes.

Reference entry:

```
`@Article{Mosley2007,
Title                    = {{Racing to the Bottom or Climbing to the Top?
Economic Globalization and Collective Labor Rights}},
Author                   = {Mosley, Layna and Uno, Saika},
Journal                  = {Comparative Political Studies},
Year                     = {2007},
Number                   = {8},
Pages                    = {923-948},
Volume                   = {40}
}`
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!